# Using UserPassesTestMixin (class based view) AND redirect as well

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-class-based-views, django-users

I'm trying to instead use the Class based view, and all I end up with the default 403 Forbidden page.. Is the order of the mixin classes correct? Does the code even get used -as in get/post or does everything get bypassed and the default 403 redirect occur?

All working examples seen so far, only point to the decorator @login_required in a function based view and use the request object to redirect to the login page.
The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#redirecting-unauthorized-requests-in-class-based-views) provides some tips, but I can't get it to work with the code below.. Putting the error stack as well.

check

```
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
Forbidden (Permission denied): /app/custom-view
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 108, in dispatch
    return self.handle_no_permission()
  File "C:\Users\me\.envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 43, in handle_no_permission
    raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

Code:

```
 class UserIsAdminMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
        def test_func(self):
            return request.user.groups.filter(name='CustomAdmin').exists()

    class CustomAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserIsAdminMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = 'template.html'
        # login_url = '/login/'
        # redirect_field_name = 'my_link_name'

        def get(self, request):
            form = CustomForm()
            # This does not work neither does setting up login_url 
            if not request.user.is_authenticated or not request.user.is_staff or not self.request.user.groups.filter(name='CustomAdmin').exists():
                return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
```

I am willing to trying out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095161/use-loginrequiredmixin-and-userpassestestmixin-at-the-same-time/47095406#47095406), if the above approach doesn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193610/5061202), you can use `handle_no_permission(self):` to handle the redirect URL.

Simply:

```
def handle_no_permission(self):
    return redirect('users:create-profile')
```